# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page error

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I'm using asp  web forms and I want to display a modal and I need to implement modals with another website data.

Now I'm using this code to open as a popup but I would like to open the content on the same website.

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="Resultados" runat="server" >
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table class="solicitud ">

                  <tr >
                      <th>Agregar OC y SC</th>
                      <th>Factura y guía despacho</th>    

                  </tr>
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
              <tr>
                  <td> 
                      <a onclick="window.open('/TEST/User/SCyOC.aspx?Number=<%# Eval("num_solicitud") %>','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=300');"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> SC/OC</a>
                  </td>

                   <td>
                        <a onclick="window.open('/TEST/User/FacturaYDespacho.aspx?Number=<%# Eval("num_solicitud") %>','targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=300');"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Agregar datos</a>
                   </td>

              </tr>

          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>

      </asp:Repeater>
```

Any suggestion for this?

I tried to use `AjaxControlToolkit` but I can't use due to an error:

> Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have more than one script manager in your `.aspx` page so remove those unnecessary script manager from your `.aspx` page. There should be only one script manager like ID `ScriptManager1` :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

> Only one instance of the ScriptManager control can be added to the page. The page can include the control directly, or indirectly inside a nested component such as a user control, content page for a master page, or nested master page. If a page already contains a ScriptManager control, but a nested or parent component needs additional features of the ScriptManager control, the component can include a ScriptManagerProxy control. For example, the ScriptManagerProxy control enables you to add scripts and services that are specific to nested components. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx).